# C: can't write data on file

Tags: c, linux

i want to open a file, write some data on it so i have to use (Fopen) " i can't use open because i need fopen in some other things "

now if i want to write on the file using fwrite it just don't i don't know why this is what i referred to in my code #option1, but if i get the file descriptor and use normal write method everything works fine see #option 2 below.

anyone can help me to make fwrite works ?

```
    char file_data[256] // has some values 
    int file_size = strlen(file_data);
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(MY_FILE_NAME, "w+");


    if(!file){//edited 
           return false;
    }


    #option 1//this is not working 
    fwrite(file_data,1,file_size,file);
    #end of option 1

    #option 2//this works 
    int fd = fileno(file);
    int x = write(fd,file_data,file_size);//
    #end of option 1
```

### EDIT

my file_data is something like this

1. 4 bytes is reserved for an integer (required)
2. 200 bytes is reserved for a string (optional)

Comment: file_data has some *binary* values or *ascii* values?

Comment: you can't use strlen() on such kind of data!

Comment: i just tried to put it hard coded on some example and still facing the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

buffered IO operations use a buffer that is managed by the C lib. Your "problem" is that fwrite is buffered meaning that in order to write to the file you most likely need to flush it with `fflush()` or just close the file.

Comment: i'm closing the file later in my code ... my problem is that it's not writing on that file and fwrite return a positive number !!

Comment: Tried used fflush ? Using your code and setting char file_data[256] = "testing" and then flushing it to a file = fopen("so_test", "w+"); works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the fopen() return value, do like this:

```
if (file == NULL) return false;
```

then, if you want to write a string fputs() is preferable, IMHO, because it communicates better that what you're writing is a string.

Since, according to your last edit, you aren't writing ASCII strings, this is what you should code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct String
{
    int size;
    char data[200];
};

int main()
{
    struct String s;

    FILE* file = NULL;
    file = fopen("filename", "wb+");

    memset(&s, '\0', sizeof(s));
    strcpy(s.data, "Hello, world!");
    s.size = strlen(s.data);

    fwrite(&s, 1, sizeof(s), file);

    if (!file) return 1;

    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: i tried fputs still facing the same problem my friend thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

```
if(!file < 0 ){
       return false;
}
```

`file` is either `NULL` (on failure) or not (on success) - there's no point in testing it against 0 as it's a pointer (therefore, unsigned).

Your fwrite call seems OK, but you should make sure that the amount you're trying to write is correct (is there a null-terminated string inside `file_data`?).

Another problem you may be facing is that you don't close or flush the file - this may cause some data to remain in the file-buffer and not be written to the disk.

Comment: no i don't think there is a null char at the end because sometimes the filedata will only hold the first 4 bytes as an integer

Comment: In that case using strlen seems wrong, as it only works for strings (null terminated).

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, the mistake seems to be at line #2:

```
int file_size = strlen(file_data);
```

This only works if there exists a terminal nul character. So file_size must be either provided for example as a function argument or the you must use the full size of the array.

The following should work:

```
int write_in_my_file(int data_int, const char* data_str)
{
  size_t written;
  FILE* file = fopen(MY_FILE_NAME, "wb+"); /* SuperJulietta */
  if (!file) return false;

  written = fwrite(&data_int, sizeof(data_int), 1, file);
  if (written == sizeof(data_int))
  {
    if (opt_str) fputs(opt_str, file);
  }
  fclose(file);
  return written == sizeof(data_int);
}
```

Note: this code was not compiled, and error handling is partial.

Edit : if you don't close the file, you'll have to call fflush instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to either do fclose(file) or fflush(file).  because fopen is buffered IO so It does not write immidiately, so to ensure that file write is done, you need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`fwrite` is used for binary output, so you have to open file with "`wb`"

Comment: The "b" flag has no effect on *nix systems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a `fflush(file);` after the `fwrite` to force the writing of the data or you can also remove the buffer completely by doing a `setbuf(file, NULL);` after your `fopen` call.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your fwrite code is not the problem.

Whenever the first byte in your file_data is \0 then you write nothing. Since the data is not a string, write 256 bytes. This code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MY_FILE_NAME "sample.bin"
#define SAMPLE_DATA  "Content Content"
int main()
{
    char file_data[256];
    int file_size = sizeof(file_data);

 // fill in some sample data
 memcpy(file_data, SAMPLE_DATA, sizeof(SAMPLE_DATA));

    FILE *file = fopen(MY_FILE_NAME, "w+");
    if (file) {
  fwrite(file_data, 1, file_size, file);
  fclose(file);
    }
}
```

You see, this is your fwrite. I use sizeof instead of strlen to determine the amount of bytes that will be written...

BR