# Writing to a file. Creates file but does not write in it

Tags: c, file

I am writing a program that reads a string and writes that string in another file which has not been created.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
 {
char s[50];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("E:\\poem.txt","w");
if(fp = NULL)
{
    printf("Cannot open file");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Enter a string\n");
while(strlen(gets(s))>0)
{
    fputs(s,fp);
    fputs("\n",fp);
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Since the "w" mode creates a new file if file is not already created,my program creates that file however it is unable to write it to the file

The double slash in     `fp = fopen("E:\\poem.txt","w");` is because i thought \p cannot be a escape sequence but i want to go to the directory E:\ so i used double slash.

However I even tried     `fp = fopen("poem.txt","w");` same thing happen creates a file but doesnot write on it.

Also checked this question but was not helpful [C: can't write data on file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215101/c-cant-write-data-on-file)

Comment: Why would the final loop ever end?  If it doesn't end, the file will not be closed.

Comment: `if(fp = NULL)` is bad!!! Assigns `NULL` to `fp` and is always false.

Comment: That was a typo and i wasted everyone's time

Comment: FYI, if you look at the man page for `gets` it says *Never use this function*. You should be using `fgets`.

Comment: Btw. Really *never* use `gets()`! It's deprecated and removed from the language for good reasons in newer versions (search for it if you need more info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in comment a typo use`==` instead of `=`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char s[50];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("E:\\poem.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter a string\n");
    while (strlen(gets(s)) > 0)
    {
        fputs(s, fp);
        fputs("\n", fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please could you format the code better

Answer (score 2):

From man page of [gets()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html):

> gets() returns s on success, and NULL on error or when end of file
> occurs while no characters have been read.

When `gets()` return NULL (on failure), then `strlen(NULL)` causes segmentation fault.

So, you can simply use `while(gets(s)!=NULL)` instead of `while(strlen(gets(s)) > 0)`